# email domain validation in php on windows

Tags: php, validation, email

I am asking for an email address through a form in my website. I want to validate the domain so that I can prevent fake entries I am getting right now. I am using the following code, but it dose not seem to work :

```
function myCheckDNSRR($hostName, $recType = '')
{
    if(!empty($hostName)) {
        if( $recType == '' ) $recType = "MX";
        exec("nslookup -type=$recType $hostName", $result);
        // check each line to find the one that starts with the host
        // name. If it exists then the function succeeded.
        foreach ($result as $line) {
            if(eregi("^$hostName",$line)) {
                echo "valid email";
            }
        }
        // otherwise there was no mail handler for the domain
        echo "invalid email";
    }
    echo "invalid EMAIL";
}
```

I am new to this and used this code from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/users-email-address-php/)

Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: _it dose not seem to work_ What errors do you get?

Comment: Why not *send* an email with a confirmation link like the rest of the world?

Comment: No errors as specific. But the email address coming from the user is not validated.

Comment: `ereg()`? That's PHP 4 code! Use a validation library!

Comment: @AlexK. Can you be more specific

Comment: @delboy1978uk outdated? can u suggest an alternative? please be more specific if u can.

Comment: use an email validation class to check it's valid syntax. Then when someone registers, email them a code which they click to activate! Then you know it's real! I suggest https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-validator/validators/email-address/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can simply ping like this.

```
 function myCheckDNSRR($email_address)
    { 
        if(!empty($email_address)) {
            $hostName=strstr($email_address, '@');
            $hostName=str_replace("@","www.",$hostName);
            exec("ping " . $hostName, $output, $result);
            if ($result == 0){
                 echo "valid email";
            }
            else{
                 echo "invalid email";
            }
    } 
 }
```

call it like

```
  echo myCheckDNSRR("sample@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Still not downloading sir. @Error404

Comment: the code must work (tested) if not then you must have some other problem, may be permission issues or something

Comment: does this code work on windows? I mean does it support all windows  versions?

Comment: Hey, thanks it worked, I miss interpreted if condition. This code validates all domains right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a validation lib like https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-validator/validators/email-address/

```
$validator = new Zend\Validator\EmailAddress();

if ($validator->isValid($email)) {
    // email appears to be valid
} else {
    // email is invalid; print the reasons
    foreach ($validator->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
    }
}
```

Create a table in your DB for storing an email link code. When someone registers, mark the user as unactivated until he clicks the link in the email. This way, you know it's real, and can activate the user.

Comment: The website is in core PHP sir. It will cause and issue wont it?

Comment: Thats not a problem. You can use the components without the entire framework :-) Just download the lib, and require in the class you need!